# Unable to display json data in Ionic 4 ANGULAR

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to display the name from the JSON data given below.

which should be simple  `{{ pet.name }}` but it shows error `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` and when trying to display `{{ pet }}` it shows `[ Object object]`

```
 {
  "owner_id": "5d9ea2ae8a8af92ddfg2102c129",
  "_id": "5f5a2da89e132f446a9cfdfg857",
  "pet_type": "dogs",
  "name": "watson",
  "breed": "pug",
  "profile_pic": "bbKk882CMtyoypj2plv6QFX3sssnDe9A.jpeg"
}
```

Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: You may need to use the conditional operator like this `{{ pet?.name }}` if your data is loaded from an external source and not available when the HTML template loads initially.

Comment: @wesley thank you for your response this is the exact solution that helped me.

Comment: Glad to hear :)